# Download file with AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, download

I am trying to append some details in to a file and add that for download.

I am using JavaScript and PHP for this purpose.. Clicking download button, it will fire an AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"php/test.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: { totalQuery : test1, },

  success: function(finalEntityList){
  },
});
```

Lets assume `test.php` has a single line code

```
$html="Test";
```

Now I want to add this to a file and make it available for download.  I've used the code

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($output, $html);
fclose($output);
```

But the download will not start automatcially... I've to open the POST request link using firebug so that the download will be initiated.. what could be wrong??

Comment: Put your filename in quotes `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');`

Comment: @jav - If you are going to be editing a post - try to fix **ALL** the problems - [not just one or two mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11684714/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need to do is simply return the **path** of the file with your AJAX call and then use JavaScript to "initiate" the download by using one of the following -

- `window.open`
- `window.location.href`

```
$.ajax({
  url:"php/test.php",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { totalQuery : test1, },

  success: function(response){
    // initiate download using direct path to file
    window.location.href = response.URL;
  }
});
```

Now your `test.php` file will only need to return the URL path for the download file in a JSON format -

```
$filename = 'data.csv';
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/downloads/';
echo json_encode(array('URL'=>$path.$filename));
```

You might consider returning the URL as a raw string - but I feel using JSON might be better because you can easily add additional information in to the response without needing additional parsing functions.  All this makes it a more robust choice.

Comment: Im not sure, bt what could be the default path while using php for file download

Comment: The path is simply the URL that represents the file.  If the file sits in your web root folder then its simple your site name and the file name - `http://yourdomain.com/data.csv`

Comment: The path is where the script is located, so if the script is in `http://yourdomain.com/script/download.php` then the fileroot for that script is `http://yourdomain.com/script/`

Answer (score 0):

It requires some more parameters and headerinfo:

```
$file = "data.csv";
$mime_type = "text/csv";
$size = filesize($file);
$name = rawurldecode($name);

@ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

// required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

/* The three lines below basically make the
download non-cacheable */
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

// multipart-download and download resuming support
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end)
    {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } 
    else
    {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
} 
else
{
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
}

/* output the file itself */
$chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
$bytes_send = 0;
if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && (!connection_aborted()) && ($bytes_send<$new_length))
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // is also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
    fclose($file);
} 
else 
    die('Error - can not open file.');
```

Comment: What about the JavaScript side?  This looks like it would initiate a file download - but how would it behave when initiated by a jQuery AJAX call?

Comment: You can set the `$file` variable to a POST variable: `$file = $_POST['file'];` then make a form to POST to the PHPscript (preferably  with `target="_blank"` to open a new tab/window where the file will be downloaded. In Chrome and FF the tab will autoclose and initiate the download. In IE a new window will open, and the user will be asked what to do with the file (open/save/cancel))